# Have a repeating alarm start thirty seconds once started then once a day afterward in Android

Tags: android

I have set up an alarm to run a service to grab events from the internet. The following is how I implemented it however it seems to run immediately and not delay the alarm at all.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()+30000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, newsAlarm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [AlarmManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), I think you might want to use:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis()+30000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, newsAlarm);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `SystemClock.currentTimeMillis()`, not `currentThreadTimeMillis()`  The thread time is the number of millis since the thread was created. I think you want a real time in this context.